# Capturing the image view count on click while using jquery fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

does anyone have an idea on how I could capture the image id when a user clicks the next / previous button in Fancybox? I like how Fancybox changes depending on the size of the image so I prefer to use this over some of the other galleries that I have seen. Has anyone successfully done this? The site is in PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask :)

Comment: thanks, I will go through now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be to "proxy" your images by a PHP script.

This script would:

1. add 1 to the view count of the image
2. serves the image to the browser (instead of serving an HTML page as usual)

You would then update the `src` attribute of your pictures `img` tag :

```
<img src="mypicture.png"/>
```

would become

```
<img src="view_picture.php?picture=1"/>
```

Note that you **must** be careful and not authorize a filename in the picture parameter and/or carrefully check that the user is not trying to see a file that you don't want to show him (think view_picture.php?picture=../.htpasswd )

Comment: Adrien, that worked great. The pictures are open to the public, theres nothing that I want to hide. Are there any security risks to this aside from the normal ones like sql injection?

Comment: Yes, there is something that you want to hide: Any file that is _not_ in your image folder. That's what adrien meant. src="view_picture.php?view_picture.php" would offer your script source for download. Or other things on the server filesystem.

Comment: Two things. If the url is view-picture.php?pid=27 and this brings up a file that simply takes the id, logs it then appends it to the img src tag that is echoed out, am I still vulnerable? Second, all the sudden the width won't open on the fancybox, it is set to 0, any ideas?

Comment: It will be safe using ids (provided that you have a way to translate your id into a filename). Be carefull : you don't want to echo an img tag, but to echo the whole image file, using for instance `echo file_gets_content($filename);`

Comment: <?php
require_once(../classdirectory/logging.class.php');
log= new log();
$id=$_GET['id'];
$log->insertPhotoView($id);
?>
<img src='../photos/<?=$id?>.jpg'>

This would be roughly my picture-view file.  Is this leaving me open for something. I have the proper code to secure against injection but I obviously dont want my files to be downloadable. Also, any idea why all the sudden the width isnt automatically showing?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a general website analytics software, like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). This will give you additional insights on you visitors and their actions on your site, rather than a simple image view counter.

I am running a site that uses Fancybox and Piwik, all image views through Fancybox will automatically show up in the **Downloads** section of Piwik reports without any additional configuration.

But you could easily customize this through Fancybox's `onComplete` callback and Piwik's `trackPageView()`. See [Piwik Javascript API](http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-manually-trigger-a-page-view-on-click-or-on-js-event) and [Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api) for details.